# How to precisely time-align mouse events and audio recording events in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, audio-recording, data-synchronization

How can we time-align mouse events and recorded audio data the most accurately possible, in terms of time precision?

Or, more technically: how can we estimate the time offset (relative to `performance.timing.navigationStart`) of the beginning of the `AudioContext/ScriptProcessor` audio recording?

My webapp collects mouse events and, at the same time, records audio data from the microphone (using `AudioContext` and `ScriptProcessor`).

As a dummy test for time-alignment, I click the mouse close to the microphone so that I produce a sound while pressing the mouse button (or tapping the touchscreen): I can log the `event.timeStamp` property (which is referred to `performance.timing.navigationStart` [see event.timeStamp in Chrome > 49](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/high-res-timestamps)) of both the mouse `onmousedown` event and the audio data processing event `onaudioprocess`. The time of the beginning of the audio recording is estimated the first time the `onaudioprocess` event is fired, on the basis of the timestamp of the event. Since Chrome supports a `baseLatency` ([see AudioContext.baseLatency](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/baseLatency)), I subtract it to the timestamp (or should I add it? I'm not sure about that). The code below shows the estimation of `_startRecTime`.

I am currently testing it on Chrome 69 (on a Windows PC hexacore and on an ASUS quadcore tablet with Android).

Thanks to @Kaiido's suggestion to use the `onmousedown` event rather than `onclick`, now I reach a delay/anticipation of +/- 0.03 seconds, while my goal is to achieve an error of +/- 0.01 seconds maximum.

Is there a better way to estimate `_startRecTime`?

Here is a minimal code to monitor the mouse click events and audio events timing. Note the https protocol should be used to make the audio recording working properly:

```js
var myAudioPeakThreshold = 0.001;
var myInChannels = 2;
var myOutChannels = 2;
var myBitsPerSample = 16;
var mySampleRate = 48000;
var myBufferSize = 16384;
var myLatency = 0.01;

var _samplesCount = 0;
var _startRecTime = 0;

function debug(txt) {
  document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML += txt + "\r\n";
}

function onMouse(e) {
  var tClick = e.timeStamp/1000;
  debug("onMouse: " + tClick.toFixed(6));
}

function myInit() {
  // thanks to Kaiido for pointing out that in this
  // context "onmousedown" is more effective than "onclick"
  document.getElementById("clickMe").onmousedown = onMouse;
  
  debug("INFO: initialising navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia");
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: {
        channelCount: myInChannels,
        latency: myLatency,
        sampleRate: mySampleRate,
        sampleSize: myBitsPerSample
      },
      video: false
    })
  .then(
    function(stream) {
      debug("INFO: navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia initialised");
      var audioContext = new AudioContext;
      var audioSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
      
      debug("INFO: baseLatency is: " + (audioSource.context.baseLatency ? audioSource.context.baseLatency.toFixed(3) : "unknown") + "s");
      debug("INFO: sampleRate is: " + audioSource.context.sampleRate.toFixed(0) + "Hz");
      this.node = audioSource.context.createScriptProcessor.call(
        audioSource.context,
        myBufferSize,
        myInChannels,
        myOutChannels);
      
      // audio data processing callback
      this.node.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
        var samplesCount = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0).length;
      
        // init timing
        if(_samplesCount == 0) {
          _startRecTime = e.timeStamp/1000 - samplesCount / audioSource.context.sampleRate;
          if(typeof audioSource.context.baseLatency !== "undefined") {
            _startRecTime -= audioSource.context.baseLatency;
          }
        }
        
        // simple peak detection
        var tPeak = 0, i = 0;
        while(i < samplesCount) {
          if(e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0)[i] > myAudioPeakThreshold) {
            tPeak = _startRecTime + (_samplesCount + i)/audioSource.context.sampleRate;

            debug("onPeak : " + tPeak.toFixed(6));
            break;
          }
          i++;
        }
        _samplesCount += samplesCount;
      }

      // connect the node between source and destination
      audioSource.connect(this.node);
      this.node.connect(audioSource.context.destination);
      return;
    })
  .catch(
    function(e) {
      debug("ERROR: navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia failed");
      return;
    });
}
```

```html
<body onload="myInit()">
<button id="clickMe" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">click me</button>
<pre id="debug"></pre>
</body>
```

Comment: Note that screens update every 16ms. Your desired latency is 10ms. Although 100ms you're getting can be noticable, in most cases human won't experience latency if it's under around 50ms, especially with sounds from real world.

Comment: Not too much time right now to dig in there, but first, remember that the click event is the last event being propagated from your actual gesture. Depending on your mouse device, you might prefer either mousedown or mouseup. Then you might want to reduce the size of your buffer: the smaller it will be the higher onaudioprocess rate should be.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido: yes, the `onmousedown` event is more effective in this context. I modified the code accordingly, and I added the estimation of the beginning of the audio recording (see `_startRecTime`, whose estimation is the real core of this question). Now my error decreased from +/- 0.100 seconds to +/- 0.030 seconds. Also, reducing the size of the buffer as you suggested helps a bit. However, the error I measure is not constant, and my question is again: Is my estimation of `_startRecTime` correct? Can I do better than this?